# How do I get picocli to parse `"--item --item foo"` as `[null, "foo"]` `:List<String>`

Tags: java, picocli

I have a parameter named `--msg-content-list-item`

```java
public class CliProtonJ2Sender implements Callable<Integer> {

    @CommandLine.Option(
        names = {"--msg-content-list-item"},
        arity = "0..1",
        defaultValue = CommandLine.Option.NULL_VALUE)
    private List<String> msgContentListItem;


    // ...
}
```

I wish for the following test to pass

```java
    @Test
    void test_msgContentListItem() {
        CliProtonJ2Sender a = new CliProtonJ2Sender();
        CommandLine b = new CommandLine(a);
        CommandLine.ParseResult r = b.parseArgs("--msg-content-list-item", "--msg-content-list-item", "pepa");

        // https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Bypass-Encapsulation
        List<String> v = Whitebox.getInternalState(a, "msgContentListItem", a.getClass());
        assertThat(v).containsExactly(null, "pepa");
    }
```

But it doesn't and I get

```
missing (1): null
---
expected   : [null, pepa]
but was    : [pepa]
```

How do I define `@CommandLine.Option` to behave the way I want?

Comment: Feature request https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/1993

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a [bug](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/1993) which is now fixed.

Prior to version 4.7.2, use the workaround in my other answer.

As of picocli 4.7.2, use the `fallbackValue` like this

```java
@Option(names = {"--list"}, arity = "0..1", fallbackValue = CommandLine.Option.NULL_VALUE)
List<String> list;
```

from https://github.com/remkop/picocli/blob/2944addb8ba34d2ee6f97564bd43128bb62ec382/src/test/java/picocli/FallbackTest.java#L192-L193

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a bug/inconvenience. In method `consumeArguments`, at https://github.com/remkop/picocli/blob/main/src/main/java/picocli/CommandLine.java

```
            // now process the varargs if any
            String fallback = consumed == 0 && argSpec.isOption() && !OptionSpec.DEFAULT_FALLBACK_VALUE.equals(((OptionSpec) argSpec).fallbackValue())
                    ? ((OptionSpec) argSpec).fallbackValue()
                    : null;
            if (fallback != null && (args.isEmpty() || !varargCanConsumeNextValue(argSpec, args.peek()))) {
                args.push(fallback);
            }
```

Because `((OptionSpec) argSpec).fallbackValue()` returns `null`, it is understood as if there was no `fallbackValue`, and therefore the `if (fallback != null` does not push the fallback value to `args`.

### Workaround

Define your own `fallbackValue` magic string and a `converter` that later converts it to `null`. The convertor runs after `consumeArguments` completes (with the `failbackValue`).

```
public static final String MY_NULL_VALUE = "MY_" + CommandLine.Option.NULL_VALUE;

public class MyNullValueConvertor implements CommandLine.ITypeConverter<String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(String value) throws Exception {
        if (value.equals(MY_NULL_VALUE)) {
            return null;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

```
    @CommandLine.Option(
        names = {"--msg-content-list-item"},
        arity = "0..1", fallbackValue = MY_NULL_VALUE,
        converter = MyNullValueConvertor.class)
    private List<String> msgContentListItem;
```